# Jimp read, resize and display image from url

Tags: node.js, express, image-resizing

I can now get some data of picture from url, when I do something like this:

```
Jimp.read("https://someurl/04fc0d67a91bbd3b7e07.jpeg", function (err, image) {

        console.log(image.bitmap.data)
        res.end(image.bitmap.data)
    });
```

I get buffer

> Buffer 3d 3b 20 ff 41 3f 24 ff 46 44 29 ff 4c 4a 2f ff 4e 4c 31 ff 4b
>   49 2e ff 47 43 2a ff 42 3e 25 ff 34 31 1a ff 2d 2a 13 ff 27 24 0f ff
>   25 22 0d ff 21 20 . >..

Is possible to resize image and then retrive that image in response?

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for [resizing](https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp/tree/master/packages/plugin-cover) you could try something like

```js
jimp.read("https://i.imgur.com/2j12AxI.jpg").then(image => {

  //resize image using "contain" mode
  image.contain(100, 150);

  //retrieve image
  image.getBase64Async(jimp.MIME_JPEG).then(newImage => {
    let tag = document.createElement("img");
    tag.src = newImage;
    document.getElementById("img-container").append(tag)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jimp/0.16.1/jimp.js"></script>

<div id="img-container"></div>
```

This is just a basic demonstration of how to downscale with a given target width/height. By default, it adds black borders if your numbers don't match.
There's another plugin to [scale while keeping aspect ratio](https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp/tree/master/packages/plugin-cover). The documentation looks pretty straightforward so you'll be able to find additional examples.